# Getting started with cluster analysis in R

Tags: r, clustering

I have a huge dataset which contains 20 columns and many rows.
I have done clustering in SAS, Knime and SPSS, but I am new to R.
I have to do clustering on my dataset. 
I have imported my data into R.

- What are some suggestions for getting started with cluster analysis in R?

Comment: For reference, this Q was asked on SO where I attempted an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648383/clustering-in-r It would appear the OP has not attempted to improve the quality of their question in the meantime

Comment: What kind of clustering method would you like to use?

Comment: as u said 3 lines of code is enough for my dataset...could u please mention those 3 lines then directly i wil copy it and paste onto the console...

Comment: @nico not a particular kind....in sas, knime and spss when i give the dataset that itself groups into clusters people who are having similar characterstics...in the same way i need those clusters here in r language also is it possible to get like same sas, knime and spss??

Comment: @sridher: clustering data is not a trivial issue. You can cluser of data in several way and get several different results. It's up to you to understand which method to use and when. Unless you want us to do your work you should start by studying some books about clustering. Once you understand the concept then you can easily do it with the more than explicative code that was given you on StackOverflow.

Comment: so is it must to do coding to get in r language to get clusters or are there any inbuilt methods to use directly for beginners to get the clusters for the dataset?

Comment: I dont know what exactly you want to know. pleae explain with reproducible example, with small dataset.
Always a good way to know about the particulare methods in R, is to look the task views on CRAN. "Cluster" task view on CRAN. A quick overview of clustering in R can be found at
[R-Cluster Anlaysis][1] [1]: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html

Comment: for example if we want to do target marketing we have to group the people who are having similar characterstics.....so i have the dataset which contains people age, sex, mon.sal like this more than 20 columns are there now i have to cluster for the target marketing...this is the task

Comment: @sridher I've tried to reword your question to reflect what I think you are asking. Feel free to edit it if I have misconstrued your question.

Comment: @jeromy no it was correct only i wil edit if i feel so...:-)

Comment: @sridher Are you *incapable* of reading my answer? In one of the comments I told you exactly which three lines. But you *can't* just copy and paste it in, because I didn't have your data so used my own code/data and the objects don't have the same names as yours. All of this is included in my answer and the comments if you bother to look.

Comment: sorry to make u angry.....Yes its just my 2nd use for r language....i pasted those into console but giving errors....so wanted to see those exact 3 lines here without confusion...sorry really

Comment: @Gavin but thanks alot for ur response...as u said i'm really incapable of getting u in this r clustering concept....

Answer (score 17):

```
## dummy data
require(MASS)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(mvrnorm(100, mu = c(2,6,3), 
                          Sigma = matrix(c(10,   2,   4,
                                            2,   3, 0.5,
                                            4, 0.5,   2), ncol = 3)))
```

So my data are in object `dat`, you have read your data in and called it something. Use that object instead of `dat` in this code below:
**[@sridher - the codes below are the three lines I mentioned!]**

```
set.seed(2) ## *k*-means uses a random start
klust <- kmeans(scale(dat, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE), centers = 3)
klust
```

The first line (`set.seed(2)`) fixes the random number generator at a given starting point so the results are reproducible. We do this because `kmeans()`, if not given the starting cluster centres will randomly choose `centers` samples from your data as the cluster centres.

The second line calls `kmeans()` on the standardised data (all the variables in my data set are in different units, so scaling them to zero mean and unit variance would seem appropriate). We ask for 3 groups by specifying `centers = 3`.

The third line prints the fitted *k*-means object to the screen showing the output from the function.

This is **just** an example though. Why three groups? I don't even do any subsequent analysis of the clustering solution. Furthermore, you probably want to run the `kmeans()` code several times to make sure you get similar clusterings each time, but using different random starts --- set a different seed for each run.

**There is a lot more to clustering than just throwing your data at an algorithm!**

You can automate that bit to some extent using the `cascadeKM()` function in package `vegan`:

```
require(vegan)
fit <- cascadeKM(scale(dat, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE), 1, 4, iter = 100)
plot(fit, sortg = TRUE)
```

which suggests 2 groups is the best solution for these data:

[image: cascadeKM output]

but we know the data generation process had three groups, and as such *k*-means and the summary stats of the results have not been able to correctly identify the presence of three groups in this small sample of data.

With some real data this time, using the famous Iris data set

```
fit2 <- cascadeKM(iris[,1:4], 1, 4, iter = 100)
plot(fit2, sortg = TRUE)
```

which clearly favours 3 groups,

[image: iris cascadeKM output]

, which is good seeing as there really are three species in the data set

```
> with(iris, unique(Species))
[1] setosa     versicolor virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Comment: wow u r really amazing gavin....great to see good patience from u....this time i understood well....and when i pasted 3 lines into the console i got this error Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: So your data contains non-numeric variables. Subset the data to only include the numeric ones.

Comment: My very +1 for this instructive response (which nicely complements the other one you gave on SO, btw). For the OP @sridher who seems to wonder about understanding how Cluster Analysis works, there are a lot of clustering tutorials, including [this one](http://www.norusis.com/pdf/SPC_v13.pdf) or [this one](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch8.pdf) (both in PDF).

Answer (score 4):

A lot of people coming from SAS or SPSS to R find the [Quick-R website useful](http://www.statmethods.net/).
There is a page on [cluster analysis](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html) which you may find useful in getting you started.